# 16bit Stero Video Capture pixel wise bit separation

Tags: python, opencv, stereo-3d

I have a stereo camera that outputs the image of camera in the following format using UVC standard.
The camera device is OVRvision PRO

[image: Stereo Video Output]
The camera is directly connected to PC using USB cable and the video stream is obtained using the VideoCapture class in opencv (python)

The information I have from docs is that each pixel, the upper 8 bits are transmitted as the left eye, and the lower 8 bits are transmitted as the right eye the 16 bit data of the pixel.

The dtype I am getting in frame is uint8

The I am unsure how to proceed with separating bits each pixel in the video capture. I would appreciate any help.

Comment: Instead of posting a screenshot of the whole window, could you, please, save just the image (say, using `cv2.imwrite` to write a PNG image)?

Answer (score 0):

`cv2.VideoCapture` will return numpy arrays, so if they're 16bit, they should have datatype `np.uint16`.

In that case, the solution is trivial: do the same thing as you'd do to split a single 16bit value. Numpy provides a vectorized version of all the necessary operators.

- Right:

  - Cast to `np.uint8` (upper bits are discarded)

    ```
    right = np.uint8(frame)
    ```
- Left:

  - Shift right by 8 bits
  - Cast to `np.uint8`

    ```
    left = np.uint8(frame >> 8)
    ```

---

In case the input image was downscaled to 8-bit depth, you will be left with two 16-level images. To retrieve the two components, you just have to slightly modify the approach...

Example in console:

```
>>> a = np.ones((4,4),np.uint8) * 0x73
>>> a & 0xF
array([[3, 3, 3, 3],
       [3, 3, 3, 3],
       [3, 3, 3, 3],
       [3, 3, 3, 3]], dtype=uint8)
>>> a >> 4
array([[7, 7, 7, 7],
       [7, 7, 7, 7],
       [7, 7, 7, 7],
       [7, 7, 7, 7]], dtype=uint8)
```

Comment: When I do what you mentioned, I get the following:  
  
[Image output](https://imgur.com/a/bRkfqUW)
[Code](https://pastebin.com/Q3SJT34r)

Comment: @Nashnir In that case it seems you're not really capturing the full 16 bits from the camera.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I will post updates if I figure it out.  
As you can see in the image above your comment, I am getting output from both the cameras as I can see 2 screws instead of the one that is actually there.

Comment: @Nashnir Oh, I see. It looks like the image was downscaled to 8-bit depth... so you'll be left with 2 4-bit (16 levels) images. Ideally you'd get a full 16-bit image so you don't loose so much information, but i'll add a solution to split up such image to the answer. | Inspect the `dtype` property of your frame.

Comment: I figured my problem to a certain degree. I will update this question and once I solve my problem.
The problem. The Videocaptured frame needs to undergo demosaicing